# Pasting multiple lines into the terminal aborts after certain commands

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, konsole

As an example, I paste the following into my terminal (with the newline at the end):

```
pwd
adb doesnotexist
ls
​
```

All three run. The second exits with a failure. On the other hand, pasting this:

```
pwd
adb shell pwd
ls
​
```

stops at `adb` and does not continue to paste or execute `ls`.

1. What mechanism is at work here to abort the paste?
2. How can I override it?

Comment: you could use && and ; to concatenate all commands in a single line (you still can paste) ,  depending on the behavior that you want described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6152739/1810128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are running these commands into a terminal, and some commands interfere with the terminal configuration. E.g., when `sudo` asks for a password, it will clear the terminal buffer, so you cannot pre-type your password: you cannot do `sleep 5; sudo ls`, then type your password during `sleep`. Same with `rm` asking for confirmations.

I can get the same effect with:

```
ls
script -c ls -f /dev/null
pwd
```

Meaning, if I mouse-paste these in Konsole, pwd doesn't get executed. Here, the second command surely messes with the terminal configuration, which leads me to believe that so does `adb shell` (but probably not `abd doesnotexist`).

Comment: Thanks for the info! For completeness, `source /dev/stdin`, paste, Ctrl-D is a quick solution.